# NewtonSoft deserializing a base class not a parent class of a property c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I am serializing a generic list of OfflineTransaction objects into a json file. When I deserialize the list back it does not deserialize the base class but instead the parent class for a property of the OfflineTransaction. For example, an OfflineTransaction has a NewEvent object and a NewEvent's parent is a NewDBRecord class. The issue I am having is the json file show's it being serialized as a NewEvent but it is being deserialized as a NewDBRecord.

Any help is appreciated in getting this NewEvent back instead of a NewDBRecord, etc.

Example json file

```
"$type": "DTData.Offline.OfflineTransaction, DTData",
"ExtraData": null,
"SqlStatement": "",
"StoredProcedure": "",
"OracleParameters": null,
"DBRecord": {
"$type": "DTData.Data.NewDBRecord.NewEvent, DTData",
 ....

//how I serialize a list of offline transactions
List<OfflineTransaction> offlineTransactionsList = new List<OfflineTransaction>(offlineTransactions);
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(offlineTransactionsList,settings);
File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonString);

// how I deserialize the list
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OfflineTransaction>>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured the problem out. I was not passing in any settings when doing the deserializing.

Below is the solution

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OfflineTransaction>>(File.ReadAllText(fileName),settings);
```